# Overcoming 'field_initializer_not_assignable' error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've created a model class and am having trouble with the error: 'field_initializer_not_assignable'

Solutions I've come up with:

1. use 'ignore_for_file:...'. This solutions works, but I don't like it. (For context, Flutter's default lints do not produce this error, but I'm using VGV's very_good_analysis so I am getting the error.)
2. type cast the value. This solutions also works, but it then produces the following warning in the debug console: `Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.` 
   This is only a warning (the program compiles and runs), but again, I don't like it.

What is a more elegant solution? I have a feeling it's easy but can't see it.

```
class Product {
  Product({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
  });

  Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
  // Without type cast I get the error
      : name = map['name'] ?? '',
  // A type cast workaround removes error but generates the warning
        description = map['description'] as String ?? '';

  final String name;
  final String description;...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your concern is here

```dart
description = map['description'] as String
```

Once you use `as String` means it will not receive nullable string and therefore the right part of it never happen.

If you like to accept nullable and provide default value, you can use `as String?`, Also you've already  done `name = map['name'] ?? '',`

```dart
 description = map['description'] as String? ?? ''
```

Comment: Ah! Knew it was going to be easy. I had tried String? when I defined the variable but didn't think to do it there.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, thanks for your explanation. The warning message now makes more sense to me in this context.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)